# Is this good computer build for my Blender use case?

Tags: hardware

I've been away from Blender for a few years - I was using 2.79 then. I'm about to buy a new computer in large part to get back into Blender.

I use blender to make models and animations of my own 2 & 3D mathematical art projects - so not characters or gaming type animations. In the past I used both modeling via the interface plus python scripting and will do the same thi time around. I'm mostly wanting to have vastly improved rendering speeds for complex static models and for animations of the models moving/morphing over my ancient Windows 7 desktop (loved 7 and not so much the newer versions but oh well...).

I'm looking at a Dell XPS desktop with these options:

Processor   13th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-13700 (24 MB cache, 16 cores, 2.10 GHz to 5.10 GHz Turbo)
Operating System    Windows 11 Pro
Graphics Card   NVIDIA® GeForce RTX™ 4060, 8 GB GDDR6
Memory  32 GB: 1 x 32 GB, DDR5, 4800 MT/s; up to 64 GB (add'l mem sold separately)
< also considering Memory 64 GB: 2 x 32 GB DDR5 4800 MT/s instead but this adds $300 and not sure it's worth it>
Storage 1 TB, M.2, PCIe NVMe, SSD (boot) + 2 TB, 7200 RPM, SATA, HDD (storage)
Cooling Option  Standard CPU air cooling
Displays will probably be 1 1440p and 1 4K

Thanks a lot for any opinions pro or con.

Answer (score 0):

That looks pretty good!  I would recommend having two sticks of RAM so your CPU can use dual-channel; i.e. 2x16gb is better than 1x32gb.

If you can afford it, a graphics card with a bit more VRAM would be a good choice, like a 4070 or 4070 SUPER, since you are wanting to render complex models.  Refer to [opendata.blender.org](https://opendata.blender.org/benchmarks/query/?compute_type=OPTIX&compute_type=CUDA&compute_type=HIP&compute_type=METAL&compute_type=ONEAPI&group_by=device_name&blender_version=4.0.0) for Cycles benchmarks to compare different graphics cards.

Your storage should be plenty.

You can use [pcpartpicker.com](https://pcpartpicker.com/) to check for compatibility between parts, and building a computer yourself can be much cheaper, as you can perfectly customized it for your needs.